# Get sizeof internal go struct

Tags: go, struct, sizeof, dlv, uprobe

I've been playing with uprobes. In order to probe a specific object in runtime, I need to know the size of internal go struct. In my case, the `poll.FD`. I could count each nested struct manually, but this could increase the complexity if we are working with a lot nested struct.

My first attempt was to use [dlv expression](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/cli/expr.md#expressions) , `len <variable>`. Didn't work `Command failed: command not available`

My second attempt was to create a program to extract this information:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "internal/poll"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("size of internal/poll FD struct:", unsafe.Sizeof(poll.FD{}))
}
```

When I compile the code above, the following message is shown:

```
 main.go:7:2: use of internal package internal/poll not allowed
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way get that information?

Comment: You can't import and refer to internal packages. That's by design.

Comment: @icza thanks! What about using dlv?

Comment: I think it would be easiest to just look at the source you're interested in. You can't make any runtime decisions about a package which you cannot import.

Comment: `/internal/` is not merely a naming convention, it's actually a feature introduced in Go 1.4: https://go.dev/doc/go1.4#internalpackages

Comment: @JimB Thanks! Because I know the environment where the program will be running and the go version used to compiled the it, I thought that I could make some assumptions.

Comment: For unix: `size of internal/poll FD struct: 56`.

Comment: Thanks @rocka2q. Yeah, for that case we can easily find.  I just copied all the structures related to  internal/poll.FD to that program and run it. I did that instead of counting, because the size of the struct could be different when we are analyzing in runtime. This is because the compiler could introduce some paddings.  I am still trying to find a better approach instead of counting by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it by Testing in same package, in order to pass this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

`unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(<nested struct>))` is this what you're looking for to get the size of nested struct?

PS:This may not be answer but I can't comment.